# swift and PDFkit create specific format

Tags: swift, pdfkit

I started to use simplePDF and I'm able to generate a simple pdf with header, image and text.

I now would like to give to my pdf a format like in the picture below.

[image: pdf]

Do you think is possible? how can I set those line and table?

I can't find to much info on pdf kit?

thanks